# How to change background color of table content based on information from database

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, database

I have a table that gets generated based on the information from the database. How do I change the background dynamically, lets say if repeat == 1 then then `<td>repeat</td>` should have a background of red.

```
while (reader.Read()) {
            int event_id = reader.GetInt32(0);
            string text = reader.GetString(1);
            DateTime eventStart = reader.GetDateTime(2);
            DateTime eventEnd = reader.GetDateTime(3);
            int repeat = reader.GetInt32(4);
            string Days = reader.GetString(5);
            //string Title = reader.GetString(2);
            htmlStr += "<tr><td BGCOLOR='#ffff00'>" + event_id + "</td><td>" + eventStart + 
                  "</td><td>" + eventEnd + "</td><td>" + repeat + "</td><td>" + Days + 
                  "</td></tr>";      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to have a gridview and databind the reader, and then in databound event manage code to apply css to specific elements.

Use this link for gridview databind - http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/How-to-bind-GridView-with-DataReader-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx

Use this link for rowdatabound - http://www.dotnetgallery.com/kb/resource17-RowDatabound-event-tips-and-tricks-in-Gridview-control.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to stick with creating the table using a string you can use some helper method like

```
private string SwitchColor(string oldColor)
{
    string color = "#ffff00";
    if (oldColor == color)
        color = "#ff0000";
    return color;
}
```

and then switch between yellow and red for example, using a variable like this

```
 string color = "#ffff00";
 while (reader.Read()) {
        color = SwitchColor(color);
        htmlStr += "<tr><td BGCOLOR='" + color + "'>".....
        }
```

You can also add class name on your column, instead of adding bgcolor attribute, and then handle it using css .